# InversifyJS injecting express.Application

Tags: node.js, express, inversifyjs

I'm trying to implement InversifyJS in one of my Express projects, everyting is working perfect except the websockets. The WebsocketServer requires a built server instance, and I store connections in the express object, like this:

```
const port = 3000;
await container.loadAsync(bindings);
const app = new InversifyExpressServer(container);
const WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
const server = app.build();

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://127.0.0.1:${port}/`)
});

const wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server, path: "/hereIsWS"});
wss.on("connection", function(ws){
    let id = Math.random();
    CLIENTS[id] = ws;

    ws.on('close', function() {
        delete CLIENTS[id];
        server.set("clients", CLIENTS);
    });
    // console.log("app", app);
    server.set("clients", CLIENTS);
});
```

Now I have a WebsocketService where I manage the messages, I used to build it with a parameter `private app: express.Application` in the constructor and the connected clients are there, but I can't manage to inject the the object using inversify. Does anybody know how to inject that using inversify?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the code above. You need to retrieve an object from the object locator - container. In socket events you have the access to the parent closures where the container is defined. So, retrieve any container you need in a common way

```
const ninja = myContainer.get<Warrior>(TYPES.Warrior);
```

**@inject** - It is a helper that retrieve a service and binds it to a property of a class(two operations) that is wrapped by decorator **@injectable**. You do not need it here.